# UINavigationController background color changes that hide Back Button in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

Now I am trying to change `UINavigationController` background image with my custom Image.

I can change with following codes.

```
[navigation.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"navController.png"]]  atIndex:1];
```

So I got following pic. That pic is right and show the `BarButton`.

[image]

But when I go to the `detailViewController` , there is no `BackButton`. However I can tap without seeing it.

After I back to `MainViewController` , my UINavigationController Background is happening like following pic.

[image]

They are hiding my button. I'm thinking `atIndex:1` is making this problem because Index `1` is above `0` and All button Index must be `0`.

That's why all buttons are disappearing.

So how can I solve that problem? Please help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: why don't you use `setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:`? see the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationBar/setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)

Comment: oh. you right. i forgot to use that.. Thanks you very much. :) Please make it with answer . i will tick your.

Answer (score 2):

```
// not supported on iOS4
UINavigationBar *navBar = [purchaseNavController navigationBar];
if ([navBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)])
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"brnlthr_nav.jpg"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the appearance proxy provided by apple

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

that will set it for the entire application or you can use

```
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"your_image"]];
```